# Using SOAP 1.2 with Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, soap, xamarin

I need to use a SOAP 1.2 web service in Xamarin Android and Xamarin iOS project. Every time when i try to send a request to a web service i get the exception:

System.Net.WebException: There was an error processing web request: Status code 415(UnsupportedMediaType): Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.

```
    BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding
    {
            TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            Name = "basicHttpBinding",
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
            MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text
    };
    TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
    binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;


    EndpointAddress endpointAdr = new EndpointAddress("https://my.WebService.Address.svc");

    Client client_mc = new Client(binding, endpointAdr);
    var data = client_mc.GetUserInfo("db","user","password", "language");
```

I read that Xamarin does not support the SOAP 1.2 web services. I tried to use the CustomHttpsBinding instead of the BasicHttPsBinding, but it seems not to work. There is no WSHttpBinding in Xamarin.

Does anyone have a solution or a workaround for this problem?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What type of Xamarin licence are you using?

Comment: I´m using the one month free Trial - so it´s business.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this for a while only to realise that the Xamarin licence plays an important role.

WSHttpBinding will only be exposed in the "Business" edition and up. If you have the "Indie" license then you will only be allowed to use BasicHttpBinding.

Indie licence does not support WCF and therefore you will have a "water down" version of the C# library.

Try using Web API for hosting your services, it works well with Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to use:

```
BasicHttpBinding bind= new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
```

and to expose an endpoint on my service that uses this binding

e.g. In config add:

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicSecure">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="name" behaviorConfiguration="">
  <endpoint address="mobile" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicSecure" contract="contract"/>
</services
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions and samples.

My solution was to add a customBinding to a config file and change the message encoding to Soap 1.1:

```
    <binding name="customHttpBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpTransport/>
    </binding>
```

Best regards